# jQuery Ajax GET JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this piece of code:

```
$.ajax({
url: '/piece.json',
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
}
});
```

I am on a rail3 app, when I type "/piece.json" I get on my browser what I want. But I cant make it alert using Javascript! Why this happens?

Solved, had to use this:

```
complete: function (data_response) {

    alert(data_response.responseText);
},
```

Comment: change `piece.json` to `test.json` ?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. I just dont get anything, no alerts no nothing

Comment: try window.alert(data) sometimes alert doesn't work well in the callback

Comment: Looks to me like a file reference error.. Make sure you pass the url correctly.. Also Hit the F12 button in chrome and Firebug and check if there is request actually posted to the browser.. If you see it then good.. Otherwise something wrong with your ajax request or file reference..

Comment: firebug says that the GET request is successful and it shows the string I want, but the Javascript code doesnt work

Comment: @TrtTrt Does firebug display the json tab?  If it does not its not parsing the json.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
$.getJSON( "example.json", function(data) {
   console.log( "success" );
}).done(function() {
   console.log( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
  console.log( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
   console.log( "complete" );
});
```

Replace example.json, with the url or path of your json file.
Note the use of $.getJSON vs $get . Here's my reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 6):

It's possible that `piece.json` doesn't returns valid JSON so jQuery discards it. Try to change `dataType: "json"` to `dataType: "html"` and see if the `alert(data)` shows the output. If the alert shows your data then there's a syntax error in the json object.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you don't have a working route for `/piece.json`. Use the Developer Tools in your browser and log from the rails app to see what is going on with the XHR request.

(Look at the  http response in the browser.)

Note that you can more simply use:

```
$.get('/piece.json',function(data){
  // data is a JS object parsed from a JSON response
},'json');
```

Comment: Is it responding with valid JSON markup? Are there any JS errors in the console?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the datatype to JSONP.  It's usually to overcome the Same Origin Policy but may work in your case.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/piece.json',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use `complete` callback instead of `success`. I don't why but `success` callback doesn't fires even if all data and response are correct. Looks like some kind of bug

Answer (score 1):

Add this and see what is returned

```
error: function (error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

Comment: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"DOWN","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}